# Possible to get output from Spark App submitted in cluster mode?

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark

Is it possible to get output from my Spark App submitted in cluster mode? If so, how?

I'm running a simple Spark application using Python. The program just sets up a Spark Context and prints `This app ran successfully` to the screen. When I submit this app with the following:

```
spark-submit --deploy-mode client --master local[*] foo.py
```

it runs successfully and prints out the message.

However, when I run the same app with:

```
spark-submit --deploy-mode cluster --master yarn-cluster foo.py
```

it runs successfully, but I get no output.

While I've been using Spark for a few months now, I'm relatively new to submitting apps in cluster mode, so any help/documentation would be great!

Answer (score 1):

You can save **This app ran successfully** to external storage system such as:

```
sc.parallelize(['This app ran successfully'], 1).saveAsTextFile(path='hdfs:///somewhere/you/want')
```